# oracle adf how to visible/invisibe column?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracl adf and jdeveloper.
I have a table with 2 column(column1 and column2).
I want to  invisible column1 by click on a bottun . then when i press on a bottun again , column1 visible again.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried and what is your JDev version? You should be able to use the visible attribute of the af:column.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method in a backing bean that will evaluate to true or false, call it showCol. In the column Visible property, set EL to #{bean.showCol). If showCol returns true, then Visible is true and column displays. If showCol is false, Visible is false and column does not display.

The button,in its ActionListener property, calls another method on the backing bean that simply toggles a variable to true or false. The showCol method returns the value of this variable.

Also, set the PartialTrigger property of the column to the id of the button, so that when the button is clicked the column refreshes itself using built in AJAX. This is a pretty standard way this is done. It might be possible for the button to set the visible property directly via EL, but it escapes me at the moment.